# How to use okhttp, to operate the files on the Webdav?

Tags: android, okhttp, webdav

Because Sardine or Jackrabbit implementations rely on httpclient, but httpclient has been abandoned by Android. I wrote the Java code is always unable to compile correctly, some because of the multi dex error, some because not found INSTANCE or classes and so on ... ...

I would like to use okhttp, but did not find a little document, so can give me some tips. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check here? http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: Thanks, but how to combine webdav?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://github.com/thegrizzlylabs/sardine-android

It is a WebDAV client for Android, using OkHttp as HTTP client.

Legacy:

Originally forked from Sardine

Apache HTTP Client was replaced by OkHttp

JAXB was replaced by SimpleXml

Comment: Thank you for recommending, I will use it next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to this lib too https://gitlab.com/bitfireAT/dav4android

It's used in https://github.com/owncloud/android-library too